# Why does Python output line numbers to STDOUT

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, stdout

The following code on Python 3.8 in Windows works as needed but it outputs numbers to STDOUT and I can't figure out why. It reads the directory recursively and outputs to the text file correctly.

```
import os

targpath = "C:\\users\\ReedActed\\desktop\\" # To direct location of target file

with open(targpath + 'P-drive-test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
  for r, d, f in os.walk('P:\\backup\\'): 
    for file in f:
            fileneat = os.path.join(r, file) + "\n" # Needs the line break
            outfile.write(fileneat)
```

The file looks correct, but in STDOUT I get this:

```
99
65
75
47
41
33
```

What's creating the STDOUT output? It's not a problem just a curiosity.

Comment: This is all of the code? I don't see anything here that would print to the STDOUT.

Comment: Yeah, this is it. There is literally nothing else.

Comment: Um, how are you running this, exactly?

Comment: Open DOS window, run Python 3.8, paste code. I'm running it directly through the interpreter and not in a .py file.

Comment: OK, then is happening because you are running it in a REPL, so it's printing when things get evaluated, namely, the result of `outfile.write(...)` which returns the number of bytes written

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can you make that an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0):

This answer really goes to juanpa arrivillaga, but it looks like the result of outfile.write() will return the number of bytes written since it's in a REPL. Thanks for the solution!